# Русификация фамилий

Tags: имена-собственные

Сейчас у большинства жителей Средней Азии, Кавказа и Крыма, ранее входившей в состав СССР, фамилии русифицированы и заканчиваются на "-ов - -ев", "-ова - -ева" или "-ский", например, Караманов (крымскотатарский композитор), Айвазовский, Назарбаев и т.д.
Для чего это вообще было сделано? Раньше я считала, что это продукт уже советской эпохи, но тот же Айвазовский-Айвазян или Гаспринский-Гаспаралы жили до революции 1917 года.
Кто, когда и, главное, зачем придумал русифицировать восточные фамилии и почему это не коснулось, скажем, украинских, молдавских или прибалтийских фамилий (или коснулось, но не в такой степени)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика образования русских фамилий - отвечать на вопросы: "ты чей сын будешь?, ты чьей семьи будешь?" дала толчок преобразованию фамилий и отчеств всех народов на просторах империи. Многовековая традиция эта не затронула народы на территориях, которые входили в неё в последнее время и не вполне ассимилировались в государстве. Пример с Айвазовским, поэтому, не показателен, как и обратный вариант: Станиславский-Алексеев.

Comment: Интересно, а Станиславский-то при чем? У него это, как бы теперь сказали, "сценический псевдоним". Облагораживание простонародной фамилии.

Answer (score 3):

```
  Для чего это вообще было сделано?
```

Это не кем-то сделано, люди сами русифицировали свои фамилии, спасаясь от шовинистических взглядов сильных мира сего. Корни сегодняшних национальных распрей тянутся издалека. Армяне подвергались дискриминации и в России, и в Турции (резня армян). В дипломатических кругах даже распространился лозунг "Армения без армян", чего же Вы хотите?

Предки Айвазовского были из галицийских армян, переселившихся в Галицию из турецкой Армении. Его отец имел крестильное имя Константин (настоящее - Геворг) и после переселения из Галиции в Дунайские княжества (Молдавию, Валахию)  занялся торговлей, оттуда переехал в Феодосию и писал фамилию на польский манер: «Гайвазовский» (фамилия — полонизированная форма армянской фамилии Айвазян). Видимо, с польской фамилией торговать было легче. Иваном Ованес стал ещё в детстве - так его звали моряки, около которых он пропадал, а потом в Академии художеств. Уже в 1841 г. Ованес Константинович Гайвазовский избавился от «лишней» польской  буквы в фамилии, приведя её в знакомый нам вид. Теперь он "великий русский художник".

Answer (score 3):

Мода на уподобление фамилий образцам "титульной" нации существовала всегда и везде. Россия тут далеко не исключение.

Причины тому разные, но обычно сводятся к двум. Либо это знак приобщения к культуре того народа, который "инородец" представляет (популярно было у людей творческих), либо стремление как-то облегчить себе и детям дальнейшую жизнь - в случае наличия притеснений 
(истинных или, реже, надуманных) по национальному признаку. Ну еще иногда встречается просто произвол работников ЗАГСов и т.п.

Другое дело - повальная русификация в советский период, с тридцатых до едва ли не семидесятых годов прошлого века. Там это выходило за всякие мыслимые рамки. И все делалось далеко не добровольно... Применительно к татарскому, крымскотатарскому и среднеазиатскому населению отказ носителя от "русификации" фамилии мог в глазах ретивого аппаратчика означать симпатию к изменникам Родины. Но это слишком больная национальная политтема, не стоит, имхо, здесь слишком глубоко копать... На основной вопрос я, думаю, ответил. Причины и время для такого явления могут быть разные. В первую очередь надо смотреть на национальность того, кто носит такую фамилию: отношения к разным "инородцам" было весьма неодинаково и в Российской Империи, и в последующих государственных образованиях. "Под одну гребенку" оценивать никак нельзя.

Answer (score 3):

У Советского Союза была масса недостатков, но вот в русификации он вряд ли повинен. Большевики были интернационалистами и развитие национальных языков и культур было их пунктиком. Происходил как раз обратный процесс, например, русские названия городов заменялись на национальные: Тифлис превратился в Тбилиси, Батум в Батуми и т.д. Возможно, чиновники на местах для собственного удобства могли иногда искажать фамилии при выдаче документов, но это не было результатом общегосударственной политики.

Comment: Тина, вы правда верите в интернационализм большевиков? 
Не рассказываете только эти сказки представителям депортированных народов...  
А заодно прибалтам, галичанам, таджикам... 
Ну и прочим носителям "пятого пункта" в анкете.  
Короче, об интернационализме большевиков знают только русские.
Потому, что любой зам любого обкома партии должен был быть "русским интернационалистом". "Сам" - это уж как придется. Но вот зам - всенепременно.)))

Comment: С точностью до наоборот: 1-й секретарь - представитель данной национальности данной республики, а его заместитель - как придётся, не местный, но не обязательно русский.

Comment: Интересно, а что наоборот-то? Поясните разницу. 
Если Вы про "главного" - то нет. Как получится. 
Биографию Брежнева почитайте хотя бы. Как он мог быть "местным" в Молдавии, например?   

Но это не предмет для обсуждения в теме об "интернационализме" большевиков. 
Те же яйца, только вид сбоку. Это сегрегация называется, а не интернационализм.

Comment: В советский период был как интернационализм, так и "борьба с космополитизмом". Если брать раннюю историю Советского государства, то там провозглашалась и **осуществлялось** уравнение всех народов в правах. Бесписьменным народам письменность давали на основе латинского алфавита, так как после скорой Мировой революции это ускорит интеграцию. Отход от космополитизма начался толко после укрепления Сталина и провозглашения доктрины построения социализма в отдельно взятой стране.

Comment: Ну так я и сказал, что "русификация" началась с тридцатых годов. Когда "космополиты" в основном уже были вычищены из всех структур, особенно влсастных.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с Людмилой. Но причины тому не только шовинистические взгляды. Причины могут быть разными. Например, я сам бакинский армянин, хотя по отцовской линии фамилия Матевосов, тем не менее брат поменял свою фамилию на -ян, т.е. Матевосян, я же оставил как есть. Все зависит от самого человека.

Answer (score -2):

Форма фамилий на -ов или -ев является условно русской. На самом деле исконно русской являются фамилии на -ин или -ын: Данилин, Курицын и т.д. Форма на -ов или -ев является тюркской, т.е. Назарбаев и Каримов не русифицировали свои фамилии. Русские заимствовали новую форму фамилий во время татаро-монгольского нашествия.

Comment: Характерный пример: Афанасий Никитин, тверской купец, путешественник, русин по национальности. В то время все национальности оканчивались на -ин: русин, грузин, армянин, жидовин, немчин, литвин, турчин, татарин, мордвин, чувашин...

Comment: Это Иванов или Сергеев - условно русская? Разница между фамилиями на -ин и -ов только в том, что превая образуется от "женской" основы (первого школьного склонения), а вторая - от "мужской", реже - среднего рода. Никакой национально-ориентированной зауми тут нет и быть не может.

Comment: Это ахинея только лишь для дилетантов. А специалистам это давно известно. Данная тема не имеет отношения к этому форуму. Лексика изменилась. До прихода татар у русских не было фамилий Петров, Иванов, Сидоров.... Позже они узнали о существовании Касымова, Джафарова, Кайметова, Ахмедова и им подобным.

Comment: «Не рассказываете только эти сказки представителям депортированных народов.А заодно прибалтам,галичанам,таджикам.Ну и прочим носителям"пятого пункта"в анкете» @behemothus Кстати, о яйцах: не путайте божий дар с яичницей.Идеология большевиков была интернационалистской, они ею руководствовались, когда нарезали границы союзных республик(стремясь оттяпать от России кусок пожирнее- последствия этой политики мы сейчас расхлебываем), развивая местную культуру(кстати, вы случайно не знаете, как себя чувствует кинематограф прибалтов, молдаван, грузин, и др? При Советах у них были неплохие киностудии).

Comment: Совсем другое дело личные, прагматичные установки Сталина (а режим единоличной власти превращает в решающий фактор именно особенности властвующей личности, а не идеологию правящей партии). Впрочем, и в репрессиях проявлялся своего рода интернационализм: русских пострадало ничуть не меньше, чем представителей других народов. Мой «чисто русский» дед был расстрелян в 1938 году как «враг народа», при этом никто из родственников с «пятым пунктом» не пострадал.

Answer (score -3):

Если посмотреть на мизерное количество населенных пунктов на территории Московского княжества в сравнении огромным количеством населенных пунктов на территории современной Украины во времена Киевской Руси, то возникает закономерный вопрос, почему русских стало существенно больше, чем украинцев. Неужели русские женщины многие поколения рожали больше, чем украинки? Что-то не верится. Реальным объяснением этого бурного деторождения является русификация других народов Московии а затем России и СССР.

Comment: Зачем это здесь?